# How to properly configure bindings so that data is pulled from the MSSQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity

I am developing an application that will work with a database using EntityFrameWork.
I wrote such a WPF window, made bindings by names in the Tour table, to display information about tours.
But on startup, I see empty fields. Who can tell what the problem is?
List loaded into ListView

Code XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ToursApp.test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToursApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Tours" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LViewsTours">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="20" Width="400">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="310"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="400" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <Binding Path="ImagePreview">
                                <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                                    <ImageSource>Resources/placeholder.png</ImageSource>
                                </Binding.TargetNullValue>
                            </Binding>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="390" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 5" FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5 5 5 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TicketCount}" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsActual}" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
                
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

CODE C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ToursApp
{
    public partial class simpleUser : Window
    {
        public simpleUser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var currentTours = TourBaseEntitiesDB.GetContext().Tour.ToList();
            MessageBox.Show(currentTours.Count().ToString());
            LViewsTours.ItemsSource = currentTours;
        }
    }
}
```

Ожидаемый результат:
[image]

Результат который я получаю:
[image]

**UPD** Попробовал сделать вывод в DataGrid, без изменений, получаю пустые строки:
[image]

Comment: What does `currentTours.Count()` return?

Comment: I used this for debugging, it returns the same amount as in the database - 4

Comment: var currentTours = TourBaseEntitiesDB.GetContext().Tour.Where(a=>a.Columnname != null || a.Columnname != '').ToList()